# windows update configuration from command line

Tags: command-line-interface, automation, windows-update

I'm building a script to rebuild a server from scratch.

I want to configure Windows Update as below.
I can set the first option using 
`reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate\Auto Update" /v AUOptions /t REG_DWORD /d 4 /f`

Reboot required it seems 
(Please feel free to provide a better solution)

I couldn't find a command (or chocolatry packages) for the other 2 settings.

[image: Windows Update Settings]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may do better to build a Powershell DSC to enforce this policy, and apply that to the newly built server instances. Based on my readings of http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd939844(v=ws.10).aspx, it looks like you could solve this with:

```
WindowsAutoUpdate Policy {
    Node localhost {
        Registry EnableSilentUpdates
        {
            Ensure = "Present"
            Key = "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\AU"
            ValueName = "AUOptions"
            ValueData = "4"
            ValueType = "Dword"
        }
        Registry ScheduledInstallDay
        {
            Ensure = "Present"
            Key = "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\AU"
            ValueName = "ScheduledInstallDay"
            ValueData = "0"
            ValueType = "Dword"
        }
        Registry ScheduledInstallTime
        {
            Ensure = "Present"
            Key = "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\AU"
            ValueName = "ScheduledInstallTime"
            ValueData = "00:00:00" ## Midnight. Pick another
            ValueType = "Dword"
        }
        Registry AlsoGetNonCriticalUpdates
        {
            Ensure = "Present"
            Key = "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\AU"
            ValueName = "IncludeRecommendedUpdates"
            ValueData = "1"
            ValueType = "Dword"
        }
        Registry EvenTheReallyMinorUpdates
        {
            Ensure = "Present"
            Key = "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\AU"
            ValueName = "AutoInstallMinorUpdates"
            ValueData = "1"
            ValueType = "Dword"
        }
    }
}
```

I could find the registry entries to update other Microsoft packages, but the methodology I used to get those last two registry entries was to take a registry snapshot beforehand

```
regedt32 /e "pre.txt" "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\"
```

, changed those settings and took another registry snapshot

```
regedt32 /e "post.txt" "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\"
```

and compared the two using regdiff (https://code.google.com/p/regdiff/).